# drawing circles in R to show stats analysis

Tags: r, plotrix

I'm trying to represent the number of times words are mentioned in a text through circles in R. I currently have a 2D array called allwords containing these words (15 of them in total) and then the number of times they are mentioned. for instance

allwords[1]= thanks
              ......................255

I've looked at plotrix but i cant seem to think how to make the circles not overlap using this package? I know the size of each circle is 
sqrt(numberoftimes/pi)
Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!
Alan.

Comment: Would the word cloud package help you?   https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordcloud/wordcloud.pdf

Comment: It actually does answer my question thanks Charles!